# how does livecycle work?

Tags: adobe, livecycle

i have just started using adobe livecycle . i dont need to understand the livecycle with a developers perspective but as of now i have to get into testing livecycle applications. where should i get started so that i understand basics of livecycle. for instance i would like to know what a watched folder is . please refer me to livecycle tutorial

Answer (score 7):

It's important to realise that LiveCycle is a suite of products (Some people even call it a platform). The suite contains many solution components and your approach to testing would probably depend on which components you're working with.

Having said that; generally LiveCycle applications involve PDF-based electronic forms that users can fill in online and submit to a BPM server for processing. In more recent times Livecycle can also be seen as the back-end for enterprise-scale Flex applications.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest checking out the Adobe Evangelism Team's Tour de LifeCycle reference:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/tourdelivecycle/

I've found it to be a good centralized point for blogs, turorials and documentation on all things LiveCycle.

Answer (score 2):

You might find the [LiveCycle Application Development Process](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/appDevWorkflow/index.html) useful - it highlights the installation, planning, development, deployment, and maintenance phases of a LiveCycle application.

Best of luck!
-John